# How to pass kwargs from a state file to my custom module?

Tags: python, saltstack

I'm writing a [custom module](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/modules/) to create a local mirror on Ubuntu using [`debmirror`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror). Here's my code:

```python
'''
Build a local mirror with debmirror.
'''

import logging
import os

import salt.utils
from salt.exceptions import CommandExecutionError


def created(arch,
            section,
            server,
            release,
            in_path,
            proto,
            out_path,
            **kwargs):
    '''
    '''
    __salt__['file.makedirs'](out_path)

    if 'gnupghome' in kwargs:
        gnupghome = kwargs.pop('gnupghome', None)
        __salt__['file.makedirs'](gnupghome)
    else:
        gnupghome = '/root/.gnupg'

    env = { 'GNUPGHOME': gnupghome }

    if 'keyid' in kwargs:
        keyid = kwargs.pop('keyid', None)
        ks = kwargs.pop('keyserver', None)
        if not keyid or not ks:
            error_str = 'both keyserver and keyid options required.'
            raise NameError(error_str)
        cmd = 'apt-key export {0}'.format(keyid)
        output = __salt__['cmd.run_stdout'](cmd, **kwargs)
        imported = output.startswith('-----BEGIN PGP')
        if ks:
            if not imported:
                cmd = ('gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring {0}/trustedkeys.gpg --keyserver {1} --recv-keys {2}')
                ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd.format(gnupghome, ks, keyid),
                                              **kwargs)
                if ret['retcode'] != 0:
                    raise CommandExecutionError(
                        'Error: key retrieval failed: {0}'
                        .format(ret['stdout'])
                    )

    elif 'key_url' in kwargs:
        key_url = kwargs['key_url']
        cmd = 'wget -q -O- "{0}" | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring {1}/trustedkeys.gpg --import'.format(key_url, gnupghome)
        ret = __salt__['cmd.run_all'](cmd, **kwargs)
        if ret['retcode'] != 0:
            raise CommandExecutionError(
                'Error: key retrieval failed: {0}'.format(ret['stderr'])
            )

    return __salt__['cmd.run_all']('debmirror -a {0} --no-source -s {1} -h {2} -d {3} -r {4} --progress -e {5} {6}'.format(arch, section, server, release, in_path, proto, out_path), env=env)
```

This module is working fine when testing on the minion:

```
salt-call debmirror.created /home/mirrorkeyring/ \
                            i386,amd64 \
                            main,restricted,universe,multiverse \
                            ppa.launchpad.net \
                            precise \
                            /saltstack/salt/ubuntu \
                            http \
                            /saltmirror \
                            key_url='http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x4759FA960E27C0A6'
```

But I'm wondering that: how can I define `kwargs` in a state file?

```
{% for package in ('debmirror', 'wget', 'gnupg') %}
{{ package }}:
  pkg:
    - installed
{% endfor %}

salt-mirror:
  module:
    - run
    - name: debmirror.created
    - arch: i386,amd64
    - section: main,restricted,universe,multiverse
    - release: precise
    - server: ppa.launchpad.net
    - in_path: /saltstack/salt/ubuntu
    - proto: http
    - out_path: /saltmirror
    - <WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?>
    - require:
      - pkg: debmirror
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `kwargs` as a [function arg declaration](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/highstate.html#term-function-arg-declaration) in a state file, something like this:

```
{% for package in ('debmirror', 'wget', 'gnupg') %}
{{ package }}:
  pkg:
    - installed
{% endfor %}

salt-mirror:
  module:
    - run
    - name: debmirror.created
    - arch: i386,amd64
    - section: main,restricted,universe,multiverse
    - release: precise
    - server: ppa.launchpad.net
    - in_path: /saltstack/salt/ubuntu
    - proto: http
    - out_path: /saltmirror
    - kwargs: { 
        key_url: 'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x4759FA960E27C0A6BLAH',
        gnupghome: /home/mirrorkeyring
      }
    - require:
      - pkg: debmirror
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/_hrsQd5CLvM